# How to copy only specific page content of pdf to clipboard?

Tags: automation, rpa, g1ant

I had tried to copy the whole document(which is in pdf format) to notepad and word but now I want to move at some specific page of document let say 3 and I want to store the content only of that page to the clipboard. Is there any way to do that?

Till all I know is how to store the whole document in the clipboard.

```
program acrord32
keyboard ⋘ALT⋙⋘DOWN⋙⋘3⋙
keyboard ⋘CTRL+A⋙⋘CTRL+C⋙
♥doc1 = ♥clipboard
```

Answer (score -1):

Using keyboard CTRL+A in Adobe Acrobat always select **ALL** text in **WHOLE ALL** pages.

But there are other options.

This option is available in **NOT FREE** version in example "Acrobat Standard DC" or "Acrobat Pro DC". Unfortunatelly these versions are paid applications. In these version has function named "Extract pages" and you can specify that each page as separate file. After extraction you have any file with once page and you can using CTR+A :)

But we have alternative option by using google chrome. Open PDF file in google chrome and send file to print with change printer as "Save as PDF". There you can specify page as new file PDF.

Comment: It is not true that CTRL+A select all text on all pages in Adobe Acrobat Standard 64-bit.